# Let $f,g\in\mathbb{L}_{\infty}$ then is a pseudo norm.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f,g\in\mathbb{L}_{\infty}$ then: 
i)$||f||_{\infty}\geq 0$  
ii)$||f||_{\infty}=o$ if $f=0$ c.t.p 
iii)$||kf||_{\infty}=|k|||f||$ 
iv)$||f+g||_{\infty}\leq||f||_{\infty}+||g||_{\infty}$
**My attempt:**
iii) Let $f\in\mathbb{L}_{\infty}$ and $k\in\mathbb{K}$ then by definition:

$$||kf||_{\infty}=\sup es|kf|=k\sup es|f|=k||f||_\infty$$

i)Let $f\in \mathbb{L}_{\infty}$ then $||f||_{\infty}=\sup es|f|\geq0$ then $||f||_\infty\geq 0$

iv)Let $f,g\in\mathbb{L}_\infty$, as $f\in\mathbb{L}_\infty$ and $g\in\mathbb{L}_\infty$ then $f+g\in\mathbb{L}_\infty$.

Moreover we know by definition: $|f|\leq||f||_\infty$ and $|g|\leq||g||_\infty$ this implies:

> $$|(f+g)(x)|\leq|f(x)|+|g(x)|\leq||f||_{\infty}+||g||_{\infty}$$ $\tag1$

By (1) we have:

$$||f+g||_\infty=\sup es|f+g|\leq||f||_\infty+||g||_\infty$$
I have a doubt of this last step. Can someone clarify me this?

ii) I don't have a clear idea of how solve this.

I need help for this part, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|f\|_{\infty}$ is the least number $M$ such that $|f| \leq M$ almost everywhere.

If $M_1=\|f\|_{\infty}$ and $M_2=\|g|_{\infty}$ then $|f| \leq M_1$ almost everywhere and $|g| \leq M_2$ almost everywhere which implies $|f+g| \leq M_1+M_2$ almost everywhere. [Because union of two sets of measure $0$ has measure $0$]. Hence $\|f+g\|_{\infty} \leq \|f\|_{\infty}+\|g\|_{\infty}$.

ii)  is immediate: $f=0$ almost everywhere implies $|f| \leq 0$ almost everywhere. so $\|f\|_{\infty}=0$.